# На каком языке пишутся расширяемые системы?

Tags: c#, ruby, c++, ruby-on-rails

Подскажите, на каком языке (языках) вы бы стали писать расширяемое ПО.
Например, фейсбук -расширяемое, потому что сторонние разработчики могут создавать приложения.
Если есть материалы в сети, которые можно изучить, дайте, пожалуйста, ссылку. Не могу найти

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Не существует такого понятия язык, на котором пишутся расширяемые системы"  По сути этому определению удовлетворяет практически любой язык общего назначения, применяемый для разработки (а не для учебных целей, например). Расширяемость как таковая вообще ни малейшим образом не связана с языком. Этот вопрос можно отнести к области проектирования. То, насколько приложение будет расширяемо, зависит от того, как оно будет спроектировано разработчиком

Comment: Спасибо. Если хотите помочь, то дайте более развернутый ответ, пожалуйста. Существуют критерии выбора языка, хочу в них разобраться. Либо дайте ссылку.
Конкретно -интересует на чем лучше писать расширяемые системы.

Comment: >Существуют критерии выбора языка, хочу в них разобраться

каковы эти критерии?

Comment: К сожалению, не могу ответить на ваш вопрос. Вы можете и дальше меня пафосно долбить, но есть ли в этом смысл?
Я понимаю, что логика моих рассуждений ошибочна. Но чтобы мне разобраться, мало получить вот такие скупые ответы. Вы бы например, стали проектировать на C#?
Почему когда создавали фейсбук они выбрали именно php, потом транслировали на с++? и как это связано с расширением?

Comment: >Но чтобы мне разобраться, мало получить вот такие скупые ответы 

ну так задайте наводящие вопросы. Вы же понимаете, что хотите? Тогда, думаю, у вас должны быть вопросы не столь общего плана. 

>Вы бы например, стали проектировать на C#? 

для каждой задачи есть свои инструменты. В ряде случаев я бы выбрал C#. Впрочем, не думаю, что я стал бы пользоваться этим языком, пиши я второй Фэйсбук

>Почему когда создавали фейсбук они выбрали именно php?

честно - не знаю. Но на 100% уверен, что ваша гипотетическая "расширяемость плагинами" играла тут далеко не первую роль

Comment: никак это не связано с "расширением"!

вообще как сказал выше DreamChild "расширяемые" приложения можно создать на любом языке (за исключением "учебных" и "академических").

то что вам нужно изучить это основы проектирования, для начала почитать про патерны проектирования, где, как и почему они применяются. а уже потом задавайте вопросы

Comment: Весьма вероятно потому, что php при всех его недостатках хорошо себя зарекомендовал в этой сфере. Может, потому что не было другой альтернативы (не застал веб-разработку 10 лет назад, поэтому не берусь судить, насколько хороши были другие языки для подобных задач в то время)
Может, потому что Цукерберг (или кто там занимался программированием) не знал другого языка.
Может, потому что php обеспечивал хорошее соотношение цены, качества, времени, удобства сопровождения. 

Еще раз повторю - сама по себе "расширяемость плагинами" зависит не от языка

Comment: @Santa,

    Почему когда создавали фейсбук они выбрали именно php, потом транслировали на с++

нет таких систем/сайтов, которые бы работали на PHP. PHP - скриптовый язык. Любой PHP код транслируется в код другого языка( как правило, более низкоуровневого и, как правило, C/C++ )

Comment: о, спасибо большое.
Хочу создать сервис умного дома. У меня есть 10 устройств, хочу их объединить в сеть и управлять ими удаленно. Устройства от разных производителей (разные протоколы, клауды и тд). Далее, хочу, чтобы сторонний разработчик мог написать сервис для данных устройств.
Устройства - quantified self (напульсник, отслеживающий температуру, пульс; шагомер; весы и тд) - у каждого устройства есть свое ПО, то есть  ты можешь управлять с айфона данным гаджетом. Но нет единого ПО, которое бы объединило. Сторонние разработчики будут писать программы-диеты (с использованием данных гаджетов)

Comment: вынесу отдельной темой

Comment: "Почему когда создавали фейсбук они выбрали именно php, потом транслировали на с++?"


Потому что ведущий разработчик из языков более подходящих для веб-сайтов лучше всего знал PHP, имхо.
И потом они вовсе не транслировали на C++, у них до сих пор морда на PHP, что технологически целесообразно. А внутрях еще и Cassandra есть (или уже чего другое - кто знает) на Java написанная.


А World of Warcraft расширяется на lua.


Что Вам дала эта информация?

Answer (score 2):

Что значит язык для расширяемого ПО?

Вы неправильно ставите вопрос.

Расширяемость - это прежде всего правильная архитектура. Язык - вторичен в этом вопросе.

Расширяемость - это прежде всего интерфейсы продуманные, как цепляются модуля, что эти модуля делают, куда эти модуля имеют доступ, а куда не имеют.

Не вижу проблем расширять хоть на C#, хоть на C, хоть на Python, хоть на 1С, хоть на Go...

Судя по постановке вопроса, Вам лучше взять за основу язык, который изначально придуман для встраивания, что годится и для написания расширений, например, есть lua. Ибо к нему Вы найдете много-много примеров для встраивания.

С ним будет довольно просто.

А в качестве основы, в качестве языка для базового приложения, которое Вы собираетесь расширять, следует взять тот язык, который Вы хорошо знаете.

Разумеется, необходимым условием является наличие биндинга между языком написания расширений и языком написания основной системы.